# В таблицу постоянно передаётся значение null, хотя я ему передаю значения. PHP/mysql

Tags: php, sql, база-данных

Вот у меня есть несколько php файлов и разные таблицы. Я вывожу на страницу данные из таблицы visits. Там всё по ключам выводится, но проблема что я не могу добавить в таблицу ничего. Проблема в том, что id_diagnoz постоянно NULL хотя я передаю ему переменную и из-за этого похоже не выводится на страницу, так как то что выводится вручную через phpmyadmin заполняется в id_diagnoz и всё выводится. Когда объединял две таблицы проблем с добавлением не было, но с тремя чёт не очень получается.
Код кнопки добавления:

```
    <?php 
    require_once '../connect.php';
    $f_name = $_POST["pacuk"]; // trim - удаялет пробелы
    $diagnoz = $_POST["description"];
    $dia = $_POST["quantity_vizits"];
    $name_doc = $_POST["docuk"];
    
    // Выполняем insert в БД
    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `vizits` 
    (`id_vizit`, `id_pacient`, `quantity_vizits`, `id_diagnoz`, `id_doctor`) 
    VALUES (NULL, '$f_name', '$dia', '$name_doc')");
    header('Location: ../index.php');
     exit();
Вот главная страница: index.php 
  <div class="vizit_modal hide" id="hide_viz">
            <form action="vizits/insert_viz.php" method="post" class="pac">
            <div class="diagnoz">
                <h3>Пациент</h3>
                <?php 
                    $resultat = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM pacient");
                
                ?>
                <select name="pacuk" id="">
                <?php while($row_brigade = mysqli_fetch_array($resultat)): ?>
                    <option value="<?= $row_brigade['id_pacient'] ?>"> <?= $row_brigade["first_name"]?> <?= $row_brigade["last_name"] ?> <?= $row_brigade["third_name"] ?> <?= $row_brigade['date_birth'] ?></option>
                <?php endwhile ?>

                </select>
                <h3>Количество посещений</h3>
                <input type="text" name="quantity_vizits">
                <h3>Лечащий врач</h3>
                <?php 
                    $resultat = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM doctor");
                
                ?>
                <select name="docuk" id="">
                <?php while($row_brigade = mysqli_fetch_array($resultat)): ?>
                    <option value="<?= $row_brigade['id_doctor'] ?>"> <?= $row_brigade["first_doc"]?> <?= $row_brigade["last_doc"] ?> <?= $row_brigade["third_doc"] ?></option>
                <?php endwhile ?></select><br>
                <div class="btns">
                    <input type="submit" name="add_bt" value="Добавить">
                <!-- <a href="index.php" class="add_bt">Добавить</a> -->
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
            </div>
```

Вывожу тоже в index.php

```
<div class="vizit_modal hide">
        <form action="vizits/insert_viz.php" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Имя</th>
                <th>Фамилия</th>
                <th>Отчество</th>
                <th>Дата рождения</th>
                <th>Диагноз</th>
                <th>Количество визитов</th>
                <th>Лечащий врач(Имя)</th>
                <th>Лечащий врач(Фамилия)</th>
            </tr>
            <?php 
                $vizit = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT
                pacient.first_name, pacient.last_name, pacient.third_name, pacient.date_birth, diagnoz.description, vizits.quantity_vizits, doctor.first_doc, doctor.last_doc
            FROM
                vizits
            INNER JOIN pacient ON pacient.id_pacient = vizits.id_pacient
            INNER JOIN doctor ON doctor.id_doctor = vizits.id_doctor
            INNER JOIN diagnoz ON diagnoz.id_diagnoz = vizits.id_diagnoz;");                
                while($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($vizit)):
                    ?>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= $myrow['first_name'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $myrow['last_name'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $myrow['third_name'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $myrow['date_birth'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $myrow['description'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $myrow['quantity_vizits'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $myrow['first_doc'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $myrow['last_doc'] ?></td>
                        <td class="c_d"><a href="diagnoz/update_dia.php?id_diagnoz=<?= $myrow[0] ?>" class="c_d change pereliv">Изменить</a></td>
                        <td class="c_d"><a href="diagnoz/delete.php?id_diagnoz=<?= $myrow[0] ?>" class="c_d delete pereliv">Удалить</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endwhile ?>
                    
               
        </table>  
        </form>
        </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как минимум в INSERT  задаётся 5 полей, а в VALUES 4

Comment: посмотрите в сторону шаблонизаторов, отделите верстку от кода